# SQL: Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT Campaign_id 
FROM Impressions 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31' ;
```

The above query gives me the result for the `Campaign_id`'s that have been active **on any** date between 2015-03-01 and 2015-03-31.

I want the result set to contain the `campaign_id`'s if the have been active **on all** the dates in between 2015-03-01 and 2015-03-31.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `DATE` is a `DATE` datatype and has no time component.

```
DECLARE @Start DATE = '2015-03-01',
        @End   DATE = '2015-03-31'

SELECT Campaign_id
FROM   Impressions
WHERE  Date BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP  BY Campaign_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Date) = 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, @Start, @End);
```

---

Or a version without the variables

```
SELECT Campaign_id
FROM   Impressions
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES ({ d '2015-03-01' },
                            { d '2015-03-31' })) V([Start], [End])
WHERE  [Date] BETWEEN [Start] AND [End]
GROUP  BY Campaign_id, [Start], [End]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Date) = 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, [Start], [End]);
```

Comment: Works great, gives me the result that I want. Would be great if you could tell me how the last line works, didnt quite catch that.

Comment: @TauseefHussain - If they were active every date in march that would mean that they were active for 31 distinct days in that month, the `DATEDIFF` just avoids hardcoding this number.

Comment: My bad! Apologies! That was a mistake, Facepalm!! Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `HAVING` clause with `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT Campaign_id 
FROM Impressions
WHERE Date between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31' 
GROUP BY Campaign_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Date) = 31;
```

You should also review this [blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) by Aaron Betrand to understand why using `BETWEEN` for dates is a bad idea.

You can make arrange the query to only mention the dates once by doing something like:

```
WITH params as (
      SELECT CAST('2015-03-01' as DATE) as date1, CAST('2015-03-31' as DATE) date2
     )
SELECT i.Campaign_id
FROM params CROSS JOIN
     Impressions i
WHERE i.Date >= params.Date1 and i.Date < DATEADD(day, 1, params.Date2)
GROUP BY i.Campaign_id, params.date1, params.date2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.Date) = 1 + DATEDIFF(day, params.date1, params.date2);
```

Note:  Some would prefer a `JOIN` to a `CROSS JOIN` in this case.  By habit, I always put a parameters CTE in a query using `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using between for dates, the problem only exists when using datetimes